# Spring Boot, do I even need a model with vuejs?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble understanding and then deciding how I want setup the frontend of my spring boot application. My question is do I even need thymeleaf or rather do I lose something if I only use vuejs?

First things first I am mostly into backend stuff and barely know a lot about current frontend technologies etc. However I tried out vuejs and liked it a lot.

I used to use thymeleaf and serve static html pages with thymeleaf markup. After playing around a bit with vuejs I want to use that instead.

So far I've managed to set it up two ways:

1. I keep thymeleaf and use it together with vuejs. This allows me to keep the model that I can pass in my view controllers.
2. I only use vuejs and get all information through REST from the spring boot app. However I am asking myself if there isnt a way to access the model from here? If that would be the case I wouldnt need thymeleaf right?

I really think that I'm having some kind of architectural misunderstanding and would appreciate it if I could get it cleared up.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--what does "isn't there a way to access the model from here" mean? If you're just returning JSON then you don't need Thymeleaf. There doesn't even need to be a model on the back end, but if you have to do anything w/ the data on the back end then models are good, but a separate concern from the view layer.

Comment: vue.js is a framework for creating front end "html" in JS in browser. So on the backend you do not need to use any html template engine (as e.g. thymeleaf) and return HTML documents. You need to create some "data API" instead, to let vue.js application that run on the client to send and retrieve data (usually JSON is a exchange format of chice). With Spring boot you can easily create REST API to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. 
Sorry for being confusing about the model. What I meant is in the controller where I specify which page to return, I have the option to add an object to the model like "model.addAttribute("test","object")". Thymeleaf then allows me to use that model in the template before it is served to the client if i understand it correctly. In a way the client doesn't have access to this model then, right?
So I was wondering if I lose this option to serve additional model data to my views if I do not continue to use thymeleaf or there is another way to access it.

Comment: if you check vuejs, you can generate on the server.